# using window.onload function

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
     document.write("www.sabah.com.tr opened..")
}
function start() {
var myWin = window.open("http://www.sabah.com.tr","_blank");
myWin.onload = init;  // i think the poroblem is here..
}
setTimeout(start, 5*1000);
</script>
```

i want to call init function when my new page loaded but there is a problem.. init function didnt call when page loaded.. so how can i call init function?

Comment: i changed myWin.onload = init replaced with myWin.onload = init()
NOW CODE IS WORKING BUT I THINK INIT FUNCTION ISNT WORKING AFTER ONLOAD BECAUSE WHILE PAGE IS LOADING IM TAKING THE "OPENED" MESSAGE
So how will i do something after page loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with that code:

- The function will be run in the scope of the current page, not the newly opened page.
- You can't use `document.write` after the page has loaded, that will scrap the page and replace it with the string specified.
- If the page is loaded from a different domain, you can't access it in any way.

Comment: can you look at my new comment under my question?

Comment: . i wont run the function in a new page i just want to run the function in my page WHEN A NEW PAGE LOADED.
. i dont touch to the new page, document.write is on my page
. i want to access a different domain, i just want to do something when page as soon as FULLY LOADED

Comment: @ramazan murat: It works fine if the new page is loaded from the same domain. If it's loaded from a different domain, it won't trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

unless the URL you are opening is the same domain, you do not have access to the newly created window object.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the window first with an empty URL, then performing the operation/attaching the handler, and then loading the content `(mywin.location = ...)`.

Answer (score -1):

**Try trigger function**

```
myWin.onload=$('#form_id').trigger('init');
```

Comment: `trigger` triggers events, it doesn't run functions.